# CSV write multiple items in a single list in single csv field

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I have a multiple lists which i want to write in each csv field. One of the list contains multiple items. I want to write the items in that list in a single csv field. But i'm unable to do that.My code is:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.myCSV = csv.writer(open('office-ves_04112014.csv', 'wb'),dialect="excel",quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    self.myCSV.writerow(['location','h1','count','urllist'])

def process_item(self, item, spider):
 self.myCSV.writerow([item['location'][0].encode('utf-8'),item['h1'][0].encode('utf-8'),item['count'], item['url']])
 return item
```

I'm using the code for generating csv file in scrapy. **urllist** is the required list containing multiple items. The current code returns me whole list in a single field as:

```
[u'urllistitem1', u'urllistitem2', u'urllistitem3']
```

which is not what i want. The expected output is:

```
urllistitem1,urllistitem2,urllist3
```

My spider code is:

```
class MyItem(Item):
 url = Field()
 location = Field()
 h1 = Field()
 count = Field()


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
 name = "officevesdetail"
 allowed_domains = ["xyz.nl"]
 f = open("officelist-ves.txt")
 start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
 f.close()

 def parse(self, response):
  item = MyItem()
  sel = Selector(response)
  item['url'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="text"]/h3/a/@href').extract()
  item['h1'] = sel.xpath("//h1[@class='no-bd']/text()").extract()
  item['count'] = len(item['url'])
  item['location'] = sel.xpath('//input[@name="Location"]/@value').extract()
  yield item
```

If i try

```
item['url'][0].encode('utf-8')
```

i only get the 1st url i..e **urllistitem1**

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You refer to urllist, but that is only referred to as text for the heading row. Nowhere do you use that as variable when calling writerow.

Comment: Posting your full spider code with explicit URLs and example output would make this much easier to understand and to try and troubleshoot. :)

Comment: @Talvalin : there you go !!

Answer (score 1):

Your last argument to the csv writer sends it a list of items instead of a string. I'm guessing this is because you don't know how long the list will be. No problem: you are already sending it a list, so just add the two lists together, ideally after encoding all the elements of the second list:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.myCSV.writerow([item['location'][0].encode('utf-8'),
                         item['h1'][0].encode('utf-8'),
                         item['count']] + 
                        [i.encode('utf-8') for i in item['url']]])
    return item
```